# Why my http server I created not working with http://myserver:port/?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-10.04

Recently I installed node on new server , and create this simple program.

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("Hello World!");
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

When I run this in browser http://newserver:8080/ version 0.4.10 not working .

http://oldserver:8080/ working .version 0.5.0 pre .

Why this happening?.

Comment: First I was wondering what kind of plant a "portigave" is ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've referred to a new and an old server, which suggests to me you're not running this from `localhost`. In that case, have you verified that both servers have the same firewall rules? Specifically, is port `8080` allowing external traffic on the new server?

Comment: right after adding the firewall allow it is working . is by default not allowed to all in firewall , what should i do to check next time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're serving a website over a custom port then you always need to make sure that port is exposed externally (or routed to via a proxy).

Answer (score 0):

Is someone already listening on 8080?  Try telnetting to that port and see if it works.

Comment: try telnet in window xp first time , it is not getting connected , and my old server is connecting and cmd window remain , but in new server cmd window get closed .

Comment: checked by http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/result/  isn't responding on port 8080 (webcache).